# Mongoose virtual setter does not seem to work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-schema

My Mongoose version is 4.0.7.
I have the following virtuals in my schema:

```
ProjectSchema.virtual("idName")
        .get(function(name){
            return this.duration + this.name;

});
ProjectSchema.virtual("deadline")
        .set(function(period){
         this._deadline = period;
         console.log(this._deadline);

        }).get(function(){
                    return this._deadline;
                     console.log("got");
                });


ProjectSchema.set("toJSON", {getters:true,virtuals:true});
ProjectSchema.set("toObject", {getters: true,virtuals:true});
```

So my first virtual named "idName" which I made just to test works fine. 
when I call:

```
db.Project.findOne({name:proj.name},function(err,data){ console.log(data.get("idName"));});
```

However, the same being done for my "deadline" virtual that applies setter logs undefined which is very strange. In fact, I test it like this:

```
var newproject = new db.Project({
        _id:Math.floor(Math.random()*934959349),
        name: proj.name,
        desc: proj.desc,
        duration: proj.duration, 
        team: proj.team,
        leader: proj.leader,
        deadline: "2 weeks"
    });
        newproject.save();
```

I don't understand why the virtual in combination with setter and getter do not work. Basically, I have the same set up in my User schema:

```
     UserSchema.virtual('password')
.set(function(password) {
    this._plainPassword = password;
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('base64');
    //more secure - this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('base64');
    this.hashedPassword = this.encryptPassword(password);
})
.get(function() {
    return this._plainPassword;
});
```

I don't understand why this works with the setter and internal variables whereas "deadline" virtual fails to work. Please, help

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "does not seem to work" and "do not work".  Is there an error message?  If so, add it to the question.

Comment: No error message. data.get("deadline") is undefined. whereas other virtual ("idName") which was initialized without a setter works with data.get("idName") and is returned with other properties when I transform data to JSON or Object with data.toObject() or data.toJSON